# XML Seek to specific elements, as efficiently as possible

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file-io, linq-to-xml

I'm working on an application where i have to read a specific xml node (the 'progress' node, out of a several large (3meg'ish) files.

I'm doing that via TextReader and XDocument, as shown below

```
TextReader reader = null;
reader = new StreamReader(Filename);
XDocument objDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

var progressElement = objDoc.Root.Element("Progress");           

var lastAccessTime = progressElement.Element("LastTimeAccessed").Value;
var user = progressElement.Element(("LastUserAccessed").Value;
var lastOpCode = progressElement.Element("LastOpCodeCompleted").Value;
var step = progressElement.Element("StepsCompleted").Value;
```

XDocument, I believe, is loading the entire file into memory before doing anything else. However, I don't need that!  I know the node is going to be the first node in the file.

Is there any type of 'seek' xml parsers that don't cache the entire file first?

Its taking like 15 seconds to parse 10 files for the attributes mentioned above (terrible wireless here).

Comment: would an XmlReader do? the "noone likes xml" API, but it's streamin instead of DOM.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that solution, but its startign to look like the only option.

Answer (score 1):

XmlReader is your best option if all you want is speed. It reads a node at a time, starting at the beginning. The big limitation is that you can't go backward or use any random-access to the XML document.

Comment: I'm typing up some samples right now, and even calling 'new StreamReader' on the network file takes 1.5 seconds.  I'm thinking the time penalty is going to be there regardless of whether i use xdocument or xmlreader, i'm thinking xdocument isn't the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use a SAX parser, which works differently to XDocument. Basically, a SAX parser works its way through the input XML, firing events back at callback code. (You write these callback handlers.) The main advantages;

1. The entire document need not be read into a memory model. (A DOM)
2. You can stop the processing when you have what you want.

Have a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipsaxstop/